# how to make jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in jquery.
i do not know how to make jquery plugin.
i have snippet my code Is it Proper or not?

In that error is generated due to this keyword in init function.

**error : TypeError: a is undefined in jquery.js.**

Please provide me proper way jQuery plugin

```js
;
(function($, doc, win) {
  "use strict";

  function Widget(el, opts) {
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.init();
  }

  // Plugin definition.
  $.fn.am_custum_slider = function(options) {
    var args = arguments;
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.am_custum_slider.defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      //$.fn.Widget.init(this, opts);
      new Widget(this, opts);
    });

  };
  Widget.prototype.init = function() {
      $(this).append('<ul class="slides"><li><img src="slide1.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide2.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide3.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide4.jpg" /></li></ul>');
    },

    // Plugin defaults – added as a property on our plugin function.
    $.fn.am_custum_slider.defaults = {
      sliderWidth: 720,
      sliderHeight: 350,
      animationSpeed: 1000,
      pause: 3000,
      currentSlide: 1,

      noSliders: 5,
      noSlidesPerSlide: 5,

      titleShow: true,
      description: true,
      dataSlider: {
        "slider1": [{
          "Title": "Title 1",
          "Description": "Description 1",
          "imagePath": "images/slider1.jpg"
        }, {
          "Title": "Title 2",
          "Description": "Description 2",
          "imagePath": "images/slider2.jpg"
        }, {
          "Title": "Title 3",
          "Description": "Description 3",
          "imagePath": "images/slider3.jpg"
        }, {
          "Title": "Title 4",
          "Description": "Description 4",
          "imagePath": "images/slider4.jpg"
        }, {
          "Title": "Title 5",
          "Description": "Description 5",
          "imagePath": "images/slider5.jpg"
        }, ]
      }
    };

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custum_slider"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".custum_slider").am_custum_slider();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Start from [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different patterns for creating plugins, but here are some notes based around your current code.

Note: Your `Widget` constructor is not storing the `options` passed to it, so those options will not be available to the plugin code. Your current code assumes the options are passed to `init`, but you do nothing with them.

The constructor could be something like this instead:

```
function Widget(el, opts) {
   this.$el = $(el);             // Save the jQuery element
   this.options = opts;          // Save the options
   this.init();                  // Init the plugin
}
```

An `init` method can be called on a newly constructed instance of a class (classes are are functions in Javascript). You can then pass the instance (you are currently assuming the jQuery element is passed):

e.g.

```
// "this" is the class instance
Widget.prototype.init = function() {
      this.$el.append('<ul class="slides"><li><img src="slide1.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide2.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide3.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide4.jpg" /></li></ul>');
};
```

The "this" passed to your `init` function is the instance of the class itself (as it already contains the `.$el` jQuery element property), so you only need the following:

```
return this.each(function() {
     var widget = new Widget(this, opts);
});
```

Side-note: As your audience for software will generally be global, please spell `custom` with an `o` :)

Comment: Thanks for Spell suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there :)

Try to change the init function, `$(this)` seems to be invalid because `this` context refering to the Widget object, not the dom..the dom should be `$el`

```
Widget.prototype.init = function () {
    this.$el.append('<ul class="slides"><li><img src="slide1.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide2.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide3.jpg" /></li><li><img src="slide4.jpg" /></li></ul>');
};
```